# Why is the data from firebase Firestore not coming into my view | Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

So I have tried for a couple of hours now and it is just not working. I have my firebase Firestore setup and have a collection called leaderboard, which is supposed to store users with their score. However, when I fetch this data and display it, my screen is blank.

Firebase
[image]

LeaderBoardModel

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class LeaderBoardModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var users = [LeaderBoardItem]()
    
    func getData(){
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("leaderboard").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            
            if error == nil{
                if let snapshot = snapshot{
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.users = snapshot.documents.map { d in
                            
                            return LeaderBoardItem(id: d.documentID, score: d["score"] as? String ?? "", name: d["name"] as? String ?? "", email: d["email"] as? String ?? "")
                        }
                    }
                  
                }
            }
            else{
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LeaderBoardView

```
import SwiftUI

struct LeaderBoardView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var leaderBoardModel = LeaderBoardModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(leaderBoardModel.users) { item in
            Text(item.name)
        }
    }
}
```

LeaderBoardItem

```
import Foundation

struct LeaderBoardItem: Identifiable{
    var id: String
    var score: String
    var name: String
    var email: String
}
```

Comment: Are you actually retrieving data?  You should at least print `error` rather than doing nothing in your `else`. Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through the closure to confirm you are getting data and are processing it? Have you tested your view by loading some static data into your array? Where do you call `getData`?

Comment: You create the function to call the database but you never actually call it. Instead of `func getData() { ... }` for your document grab, try doing it in `init() { ... }`. Also, you need to handle errors better. And Firestore returns on the main thread already so there is no need to dispatch onto the main queue.

Comment: Everything here is a guess as there could 100 reasons why it's not working. The code included in the question is actually "fine" (remove Dispatch per above) so we cannot duplicate the issue. Please review the following guide:  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please update your question with brief but more complete code (are you even calling `getData`?  id vs uid? does that matter?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this approach, using `.onAppear{...}`:

```
struct LeaderBoardView: View {
    
    @StateObject var leaderBoardModel = LeaderBoardModel() // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        List(leaderBoardModel.users) { item in
            Text(item.name)
        }.onAppear {
            leaderBoardModel.getData()  // <-- here
        }
    }
}
```